# javascript bind works but live not

Tags: jquery

```
function OnIframeContentLoads(){        
  $("#iframe")
    .contents()
    .find(".text")
    .live({ 
      click: OpenSingleImageEditor, 
      mouseover: function () { HighLight(this) }, 
      mouseout: function () { OffLight(this);} 
    });    
}
```

when i am binding event with .bind() its works but with live() like in above code it not works .Whats the problem here?

Comment: A small tip, You don't need to use .contents() to use .find()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a known problem with `.live`, use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

From the docs

> Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite,
>   .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected.

```
$("#iframe").on('click', '.text', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I think folks are standardizing on '.on' now

Comment: but for dynamically generated elements with same class (.text) it still not working

Comment: Gaurav, it should work for dynamically inserted elements too, http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/77V6H/ It would be hard to tell what's wrong without looking at your code.

Comment: SACB `$('#iframe .text').on` won't work with `.on` because event handlers would not get bound to future `.text` elements. It did work with `.live` however. See this http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/pJdvc/

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that .live has some pretty specific constraints that don't apply to .bind. Particularly, it won't work with any kind of cached selector. I think that probably applies to .find()/.contents().

Try this instead:

```
$("#iframe .text").live({ click: function(){ console.log('clicked') } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use jquery on() method :

```
$(element).on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()